# knockout.js loading templates at runtime

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, template-engine

I am using knockout.js with its inbuilt templating system. I define the templates as so:

```
<script type="text/html" id="subjectItemView">
   <span class="name" data-bind="text: subjectName" />
</script>
```

I then use the id of the template so having this as part of the script is a necessity.

I have a fair few of these templates in my single page application and have recently moved to using require.js to load the scripts that are required only when they are required. I would like to do the same with the templates, preferably using require.js so that my modules could list the templates as dependencies.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the require.js text plugin: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text.  Once you have the template text, you can then append it to the page in a new script tag (with a type that is `text/html` or something other than javascript).

I have been actually using a modified template engine that handles strings directly, so that I don't need to append extra script tags to the page.

My code looks something like:

```
    this.activate = function() {
        //load view model from the server
        if (!this.loaded) {
            require(["modules/" + name, "text!../templates/" + self.template + ".html"], function(Module, template) {
                ko.templates[self.template] = template;
                self.data(typeof Module === "function" ? new Module() : Module);
                self.loaded = true;
            });
        }
    };
```

The stringTemplateEngine that I use looks like: https://github.com/rniemeyer/SamplePresentation/blob/master/js/stringTemplateEngine.js

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that works well. That stringTemplateEngine is great! I wrapped the process in a require module so I don't have that same boilerplate code everywhere. https://github.com/aranm/ko.loadTemplateUsingRequireText.

Comment: Can this approach be used in conjunction with the koExternalTemplateEngine (https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine)? Or is it not possible to have multiple custom template sources?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end result to be?  Do you want the external template engine to handle retrieving the template, but then not append it as a script?

Comment: We're currently using the external template engine extensively on the project I'm working on. I'd like to migrate to this approach, but can't do it across the entire application at once - so is there some way to use the external template engine as it is, and then use this on top? The expected behavior would be that if knockout doesn't find a specified template using the string template engine, it will then defer to the external template engine.